# Question- Optional field in react's component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So, we're working with an outside company to do our mobile app. One of their lead seniors saw my code, and asked me why dont I do this:

```
class Insurance extends React.PureComponent{
    state: {
        coverageType: [],
        distancePerYear: 0,
        plateNumber: '00000000',
        isPrivate: false,
        lien?: {

        }
    }
}
```

In my version of code, `lien` field was like this:

```
lien: {
  isExist: false,
  // .... more attributes
}
```

So i'd like to ask a few questions about the pattern he offered as I rarely saw this `?` operator before, and never on state (and sadly won't be to ask that senior for at least 2 weeks now):

1. how can I make default state to be that this field is non-existant?
2. When its non-existant- how do I target it to fill it? is doing `this.setState({ lien: { /* more attributes */ } });` is enough? or I'd need to create it somehow.

   3. How do I delete it from state if user entered a lien by mistake, and then wants to cancel it? how can I make this field non-existant again?
   4. Do you guys even think this is a good approach? why is it better then the one I did? (I know this question is opinionated, would like to hear you guys' thoughts about this).

Thanks alot!

Comment: he is basically trying to use typescript optional properties check here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Comment: This isn't a valid syntax. Maybe he got confused with `typescript` optional properties? I mean you could use a `ternary operator` and `spread` to achieve a condional property, but why would you want this. Just declare it as `null`

Comment: ohh... so this syntax is valid only on TS? maybe he really got confused then...

Comment: Yep. `const obj = {foo?: 'foo'}` isn't valid javascript

Comment: @Dupocas aright tnx alot! kinda made my life easier :D

Comment: Yes, valid with Typescript only so make sure you are using typescript transpilers